# Should I add hrefLang attribute to the header using React-helmet in SSR or CSR?

Tags: reactjs, seo, react-helmet, hreflang

I have a react app that is now becoming multi regional and needs the addition of the hrefLang HTML tag. The app renders using SSR and then CSR. My question is when should I add add the hrefLang tag. During SSR or CSR?

Comment: SSR would be better, because its coming pre-rendered. Also good for SEO reasons.

Comment: I opted to have them during SSR (initial render) and client side transitions @BadalSaibo